# Imprimir mesagem quando arquivo csv carregado for maior ou menor do que 9 colunas

Tags: php, html, array

Minha aplicação lê um arquivo csv e converter para pdf. Para isso tenho o frontend em html para carregar o arquivo. Gostaria de saber como faço para mostrar ao usuário uma mensagem informando que o arquivo é inválido. O arquivo será inválido quando o número de colunas do arquivo csv carregado for maior ou menor do que 9.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Site Report</title>

</head>
<body>

<h3> Site Report </h3>
</span></span>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <labeL>
    <span>Choose CSV file:</span>
    </span></span>
    <input type="file" accept="text/csv" name="userfile"/>
    </labeL>
    <p> </p>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Upload"/>

</form>

    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='Upload'):
    $userFile=$_FILES['userfile'];
    $name = $userFile['name'];
    $tmp = $userFile ['tmp_name'];



    $extension=explode('.', $name);
    $ext=end($extension);


    $newName =md5($name).'.'.$ext;

    $newName= str_replace(' $name ','$name','uploadFile').'.'.$ext;
    $userMessage="File uploaded successfuly  ";

    if(empty($userFile)):
           echo 'Select an file to upload';
    else:
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'uploads/'.$newName)):

             echo $userMessage;        
            else:    
            echo 'Error';
            endif;
          endif;
      endif;  

    ?>

<form action="download.php" method="post">
<p>
</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download PDF File" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Já tentou dentro do lado do servidor fazer uma contagem das colunas do arquivo e se forem no seu requisito **igual 9** passar a conversão para pdf?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que arquivos csv façam indexalização da seguinte forma:

```
Email;Nome
teste1@teste.com.br;Teste1
teste2@teste.com.br;Teste2
teste3@teste.com.br;Teste3
teste4@teste.com.br;Teste4
```

Nas linhas ele põe os nome dos campos divididos por **;** (**ponto e virgula**), então tudo que você precisa fazer é colocar a primeira linha dentro de um array e contar o lenght desse array assim você tem o número de colunas ai você pode verificar se o mesmo é **igual a 9** se for verdadeiro converter se não retornar mensagem de invalido

OBS: Deve haver uma maneira mais fácil de verificar colunas / campos nos arquivos csv, só estou dando uma sugestão do que pode ser feito